# Moving code around

Tags: jquery, datatables

I was just kind of curious if there is any of the coding here that I can place inside of the dataTables script. I have the the majority of the same coding on each of my module's javascript page so I thought with similar coding I can can put all of the same coding back into that dataTables page.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnLengthChange = function ( oSettings, iDisplay ) {
oSettings._iDisplayLength = iDisplay;
oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd( oSettings );

/* If we have space to show extra rows (backing up from the end point - then do so */
if ( oSettings._iDisplayEnd == oSettings.aiDisplay.length )
{
    oSettings._iDisplayStart = oSettings._iDisplayEnd - oSettings._iDisplayLength;
    if ( oSettings._iDisplayStart < 0 )
    {
        oSettings._iDisplayStart = 0;
    }
}

if ( oSettings._iDisplayLength == -1 )
{
    oSettings._iDisplayStart = 0;
}

oSettings.oApi._fnDraw( oSettings );

$('select', oSettings.oFeatures.l).val( iDisplay );
};

$(document).ready(function() {

var pageName = $('#pageName').val();    

var oTable = $('#templatesPageList').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'rti<"pagination"p>',
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});

if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
    $('div.pagination').remove();
} else {
    $('div.pagination').append();
}
if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() == 0) {
    $('.bt_red').remove();
    $('.bt_blue').remove();
}
if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
    $('.bt_blue').remove();
}

var info = $('.dataTables_info');
$('tfoot tr td.rounded-foot-left').append(info);

$('.edit').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var templateID = $(this).attr('id');
    if(!$('div.right_content').hasClass("loading")){
        $('div.right_content').addClass("loading").load('modules/forms/edit/templates.php?templateID=' + templateID, 
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("loading");
        });
    }
});

$('a.bt_green').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.right_content').load('modules/forms/addnew/' + $(this).attr('id'));
});

$('table tr').click(function() {

    checkBox = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');

    if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');

});

$('.ask').jConfirmAction( {
    question : "Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?", 
    yesAnswer : "Yes", 
    cancelAnswer : "No", 
    onYes: function(evt) { 
      templates(evt.target); 
    }
});

$('.ask2').jConfirmAction( {
    question : "Are you sure you want to delete all selected rows?",
    questionClass: "question2", 
    onYes: function(evt){
        templatesArray(evt.target); 
    }
});

$('.viewAll').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(-1);
    $(this).removeClass('viewAll').addClass('paginateRecords');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View Paginated Records');
    $('.pagination').hide();
}); 

$('.paginateRecords').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(10);
    $(this).removeClass('paginateRecords').addClass('viewAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View All Site Templates'); 
    $('.pagination').show();          
});

function templates(whatsThis) {
    var templateID = $(whatsThis).parents('td').find('img').attr('id');
    var dataString = 'templateID=' + templateID + '&deleteTemplate=True'; 

    var iRow = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(whatsThis).parents('tr').get(0));

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "processes/templates.php", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.errorsExist) {
            } else {
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(iRow);     // remove the row from the table
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() == 0) {
                    $('.bt_red').remove();
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('div.pagination').remove();
                }

            } 
        }
    });
}


function templatesArray(whatsThis) {
    var myNewArray = new Array(); 
    var aRow = new Array();

    $('input:checkbox[name="templates"]:checked').each(function(i) { 
        myNewArray.push($(this).val());
        aRow.push($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
    }); 
    var dataString = 'templatesArray=' + myNewArray + '&deleteTemplatesArray=True'; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "processes/templates.php", 
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.errorsExist) {
            } else {
                $(whatsThis).parents("tr").eq(0).hide(); 
                for (i in aRow)  // loop over the array of row indexes
                  oTable.fnDeleteRow(aRow[i]);
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() == 0) {
                    $('.bt_red').remove();
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('.bt_blue').remove();
                }
                if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal() <= 10) {
                    $('div.pagination').remove();
                }                      
            } 
        }
    });

}

});
```

Comment: Yes, you can move code around... just copy it, and paste it at another location (if that's what you're asking) `:)`

Comment: Jeff, you may want to clarify what you're trying to accomplish (question already has 3 close votes). What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: HOw do you see that it has 3 close votes but what I'm trying to find out is with the code I have above is there any of it I can take out of that page of code and move into the jquery.dataTables.js file since most of it is used in MANY other pages so that if I want to chat any of the code I don't have to go back each page and change it in each page I can only have to change it in teh dataTables.js page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can move out anything in this file that applies to more than one page into a script file that gets loaded on those pages.

Normally if I'm deciding what to put in what file, I mark the functions / blocks that can both:

1. Run without requiring anything else to be set or bound
2. Is required or used on more than one page

Copy this stuff into another js file, import it on the relevant pages and feel a little better that you don't need to maintain a 12,000 line javascript file rather than several smaller ones.

Regarding the specific files, I don't know what's in jquery.dataTables.js but I suggest moving any of your own code out into files that are named to reflect what they do or atleast where they are used.

Not certain if this is what you were asking but hope it helps.